# BertScore giving me high results for unrelated sentences

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

so i've been trying out bert_score to do some metrics, when testing it i'm finding that it's giving me some very high scores for some totally unrelated sentences.

for example i tried this :

```
refs = ["Ladies in a kitchen laughing at the camera while one grates cheese."]
cands=["sky"]
P,R,F = score(cands=cands,refs=refs,lang = 'en')
print(P,R,F)
```

the above execution returns  :

```
tensor([0.8362]) tensor([0.8028]) tensor([0.8192])
```

I'm not sure why it's giving me these but i would assume it's not what it should give me for those two sentences.